# Confusing error on import of constants defined in another file

Tags: python

I have defined constants in a file

```
constant.py
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
```

If I import constant and print the variable value I am able to do i.e. below work well

```
from constant import *
print(a)
```

But, if I use it for comparison. it fails with error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment. Why such behavior?

```
from constant import *
if 5 < a:
    a = 10
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error, can you show a full traceback?

Comment: Me too, Are you sure you ran the second code with `import` statement included? Please also tell us the version of python you are using.

Comment: It sounds like you might have done the comparison and assignment inside a function, in which case you would need `global a` at the top of thte function. Note that this would not modify `constants.a` but would instead modify the global variable in the file that imports `constants`.

Comment: @Oli : Thanks. You are correct. Sorry. But, why the first one (only printing a) works (without global a)?

Comment: When you have an assignment anywhere in a function, the variable belongs to the local scope of the function, so accessing the variable before it is defined is an error. If you don't assign to the variable in the function, then it uses the variable from an outer scope (often the global scope). In the first example, you are just assigning to a new value to an existing global variable, which is allowed.

Comment: It determines whether a variable is local to a function when your program is being compiled to bytecode, before anything is actually run, which is how it "knows" that the variable is going to be assigned to later on.